Can I cook eggs in a pan with a plate as a cover?
Is it ok to place a similar size plate on a similar size pan? I mean like, putting a plate on top of a pot so the food can cook. Would the glass shatter? Why shouldn’t I try this? I have a small pan that has no matching lid and I have a small plate that fits the right size, why can’t I just use the plate?
Please help :/

How are you cooking the eggs exactly? Boiling frying, steaming, etc? If you're boiling them, will the heating element on your cook, still be on when you need to cover the pot?

Note that they sell "universal" lids. They don't "lock" like a matched lid does, but they certainly would work at least as well as a plate does.

Do you have an electric or gas stove?  It’s less risky with electric compared to gas (where more heat goes up the side of the pan), but if you have another pot or pan, that would work better than a plate.  Or get a universal lid.

Most plates aren't glass, and I wouldn't risk a glass plate (though borosilicate glass - some Pyrex - would be absolutely fine, and even tempered glass should be OK).
A ceramic plate or a metal one would be fine.  I often use ceramic and enamelled shallow bowls over boiling water in a saucepan for a bain marie. I have also been known to use a ceramic plate over a frittata/thick omelette that was at risk of overcooking underneath before it was cooked through, and was still too sloppy to turn over.  That's also fine.  In a holiday rental I even did this with a tempered glass chopping board/trivet as it was the only thing big enough.
The tricky part is lifting the plate off.  It will probably be too hot to lift with your bare hands, but the condensed steam will make it slippery.  So an oversized plate is better than one that only just fits, to give you something to get hold of.  This may even be OK with bare hands if it's not on there for too long.
